# Open source 3d chart controls for asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement to plot a 3d scatter plot in my project. Could anyone please suggest me some open source 3d scatter chart controls for ASP.net.

Answer (score 0):

I used `MSChart` before, it can also render 3d chart. check [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) to find whether this is suitable for your project.